# Maven Executable Jar Intermittent fallback

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I generated maven package and produced a JAR file. I am running it and successfully runs for 1-2 times then if I run it again I am directed to Whitelabel Error Page. Do you have any solution for this? I am able to search here however their issue are not intermittent. In STS IDE it is running smoothly but in jar file it is intermittent. It is running mostly for first tries.

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>censored_grp_id</groupId>
    <artifactId>censored_lot_id</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>lot-inventory-selenium</name>
    <description>Selenium Testing</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <version.junit-platform-suite>1.3.2</version.junit-platform-suite>
        <version.maven.surefire>2.19.1</version.maven.surefire>
        <selenium.version>3.3.1</selenium.version>
        <selenium-htmlunit.version>2.26</selenium-htmlunit.version>
        <htmlunit.version>2.26</htmlunit.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
          <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
          <version>1.78</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.core5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore5</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.maven.surefire}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8084

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .html

logging.file.name = some-log-file.log
```

Comment: If you're getting an error page presumably you have an error in your log file.

Comment: Please check your logs :)

Comment: There is no error in log files though :(

Comment: This was fixed already, just had to fix the annotations in the files and routing.